# Служба Windows: OnStart, OnStop, OnPause, OnContinue

Tags: windows, windows-service

У меня есть служба работающая под LocalSystem. OnStart срабатывает, когда запускается ОС, OnStop - когда выключается. Зачем нужны OnPause и OnContinue? И что происходит со службой когда я перехожу в режим сна или гибернации?

Comment: Есть такая функция ControlService (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), которая передает вашему сервису некий код. Думаю, ваши функции (кроме OnStart) - обработчики соответствующих сигналов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OnStart срабатывает, когда запускается ОС, OnStop - когда выключается.

У вас неверное понимание принципов работы служб. На самом деле, `OnStart` срабатывает, когда служба запускается, `OnStop` - когда останавливается.

А вот уже запуск и останов службы - происходят при старте ОС и при выключении. Но так происходит только если служба настроена на автоматический запуск, кроме него есть еще и ручной - в таком случае служба не будет запускаться при старте ОС.

Начиная с Windows 8, в диспетчере задач появилась вкладка для управления службами. Из нее можно запустить или остановить любую службу (включая настроенные на автоматический запуск). В более старых версиях винды это можно сделать через оснастку управления службами ("Панель управления" - "Администрирование" - "Службы" или с клавиатуры - Win+R "services.msc" Enter). В той же оснастке можно изменить режим запуска службы.

`OnPause` и `OnContinue` вызываются когда службу приостанавливают и возобновляют. Эти операции выполняются вручную, так же как и запуск/останов (ну, или другими программами). `OnPause` можно рассматривать как "остановку, но не до конца". Эти две операции над службой доступны если служба отмечена как поддерживающая приостановку (свойство `CanPauseAndContinue` установлено в `true`).

При переходе в спящий режим со службой ничего не происходит - она продолжает работать так же как и все остальные программы. Но если вам надо как-то по-особому обрабатывать этот случай - свойство `CanHandlePowerEvent` и событие `OnPowerEvent` вам в помощь.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onpause%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

onPause и onContinue суть есть тоже самое что onStart и onStop. Но на них можно назначить специфические действия.

при гибернации компьютер сохраняет все задачи на хард и выключается. т.е. никакой активности не будет. в спящем режиме почти тоже самое, только инфа остается в оперативе. при этом тоже никакой активности.

а вот если комп\сервер включен, и вы разлогинились, то сервисы будут спокойно работать